# Making offline database application on WP7 - find the right way

Tags: database, windows-phone-7, client-server

I need to build an offline database application on WP7.
App is simple - it's about making orders from our clients, then translate it to main server (MS SQL).

Spend a days read about existing techologies - but I'am still confused. Which is right for that project?

1. Sync Framework.
   Looking good, but as I understand - it provides single tables - no reference beetwen them. All the references I have to build on client side. Sad.
2. Entity FrameWork on server side. 
   And I have no clue - what can I use on client side. Is there a way to serialize entity object to Isolate Store, then restore it, and continue work with it? May be I can use Sync FrameWork, but scheme will become strange then - kinda one way.)))
3. Working with WCF & XML - most simple for me. A lot of code and conversion, but in this case I understand the data flow. In other view - I already have app with pure SQL-queries. I wanna be advanced. ))))
4. Using ext. databases (siaqodb for example).
   Which one? siaqodb suppots "Sync provider", but it doesn't support references beetwen objects - so I have to build them by myself? Any gain? I don't know.

Is there another way to build such apps? Point it please.

Comment: can you elaborate more on the details of the app and its functionality?

Comment: I read that on the appropriately titled http://www.wpcentral.com/mix11-announcements-windows-phone-rumors that MS might introduce SQL CE to WP7. So perhaps a solution to your issue will present itself that way.

Comment: 2 Morpheus. It's order-making system. Clients are WP7-phones. Main server - MS SQL databse

Comment: 2 Stonetip. I can not use their "introduce" as a database on a real device. )))

Comment: @Monochromie: That's why I entered that as a comment, not an answer. People reading this may still appreciate being aware that there will be another solution coming, supposedly in May. According to the MIX keynote today, SQL CE for WP7 will also support LINQ queries.

Answer (score 3):

If this has to be done offline, then I would generally use something like:

- storing the minimal amount of the required data within isolated using a WP7 specific database like Sterling
- using either a new REST or a new RIA/WCF service with objects/functions you define in order to provide the required data synchronisation

I think this is your option 3?

I've never really liked automatic data synchronisation. I just find it easier to code the sync and deal with the error cases myself - this is especially the case if your wp7 client app uses quite a small footprint of data in relation to the larger main server db.

Comment: You're right. "Code the sync" - my prev app have been coded this way. Now it works without any problem. And if the problem will appear - I know where to go. And "small footprint" about - you're right too.